# BDC hide identifier in new item form

Tags: 2010, development, visual-studio, bcs

I'm working on a simple bdc model in visual studio.
i use the entity framework to access the data on the database.

Everything works fine (all CRUD operations) but in the "New item" form i have to set a value for the identifier (eg. ProductId). this field is not shown in the "edit form".

can i set a property in the bdc explorer to hide the identifier field in forms?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I Have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have to delete identifier in the parameter with name "newParameter" Directon="In" for the method used for item creation.
for example:

```
    <Method Name="Create">
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Name="returnParameter" Direction="Return">
          <TypeDescriptor TypeName="AAA.SampleEntity, AAA" Name="returnParameter">
            <TypeDescriptors>
              <TypeDescriptor Name="idUnitaDiMisura" TypeName="System.Guid" ReadOnly="true"   IdentifierName="idUnitaDiMisura"/>
              <TypeDescriptor Name="dsUnitaDiMisura" TypeName="System.String"    />
              <TypeDescriptor Name="dtCreated" TypeName="System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"    />
              <TypeDescriptor Name="CreatedBy" TypeName="System.String"    />
            </TypeDescriptors>
          </TypeDescriptor>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter Name="newParameter" Direction="In">
          <TypeDescriptor TypeName="AAA.SP_UnitaDiMisura, AAA" Name="newParameter">
            <TypeDescriptors>
              <TypeDescriptor Name="idUnitaDiMisura" TypeName="System.Guid"  CreatorField="true"  IdentifierName="idUnitaDiMisura"/>
              <TypeDescriptor Name="dsUnitaDiMisura" TypeName="System.String"  CreatorField="true"  />
            </TypeDescriptors>
          </TypeDescriptor>
        </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
      <MethodInstances>
        <MethodInstance Type="Creator" ReturnParameterName="returnParameter" Name="Create" ReturnTypeDescriptorPath="returnParameter" />
      </MethodInstances>
    </Method>
```

in the newParameter I removed dtCreated and CreatedBy